# When moving elements using StyleSheet.create({ my touchable buttons move but the hotspot stays the same

Tags: react-native

When I try to move the TouchableOpacity buttons I've created by using StyleSheet.create the buttons move as expected but the hotspot (or touch location) stays the same.

I've tried position: 'absolute' in the styles....nothing else as there isn't much on the internet about it.

here's the styles:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 150,
    left: 60,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  gobutton: {

    padding: 10,
    borderWidth: 3,
    borderColor: '#111'
  },
  resetbutton: {

    padding: 10,
    borderWidth: 3,
    backgroundColor: '#ed1c42'
  },
  submitbutton: {
    top: 100,
    padding: 10,
    borderWidth: 3,
    backgroundColor: '#42f471'
  }
})
```

here's my render:

```
render() {

  if((this.state.isOn) === true){

      return(

        <View style={styles.container}>

        <Text>Timer:{ms(this.state.time,{verbose: true})}</Text>

    <TouchableOpacity
       onPressIn={this.onItemMouseDown} 
       onPressOut={this.onItemMouseUp}
       >
       <Image source={require('./assets/AnimalButton.png')}/>
      <View style={styles.animalbutton}>

        </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>

      </View>

      )
        } else if ((this.state.isOn) === false){  

      return(

        <View style={styles.container}>

       <Text>Timer:{ms(this.state.time)}</Text>  

       <TouchableOpacity
       onPressIn={this.onItemMouseDown} 
       onPressOut={this.onItemMouseUp}
       >
       <Image source={require('./assets/AnimalButton.png')}/>

       </TouchableOpacity>

       <TouchableOpacity
       onPress={this.resetTimer}
       >
       <View style={styles.resetbutton}> 
         <Text style={styles.text}>Reset Timer</Text>
         </View> 
       </TouchableOpacity>

       <TouchableOpacity
       onPress={this.onSubmit} 
       >
       <View style={styles.submitbutton}>
       <Text style={styles.text}>Done!</Text>
       </View>

       </TouchableOpacity>
        {this.state.scoreArray.map(function(item,i){

          return (i < 5) ? <Text key={i}>{item}</Text> : null}).filter(x=>x)

          }

          <Text>
          {this.state.animalArray.map(function(item,i){

            return (i < 5) ? <Text key={i}>{item}</Text> : null}).filter(x=>x)
          }
          </Text>


    </View>


      )

    } 
  }
```

I expect that when using a styleSheet that the touchable hotspots move as well! :)

Comment: OnPressIn and onPressout is a prop for 'TouchableWithoutFeedback'.

Comment: Hi hong, I see this: https://medium.com/@pavolfulop/repeat-onpress-action-when-holding-button-react-native-2c697cf28032
Which says it can be used?

Comment: When you click the link on each touch module, the module is supplied with props. Onpressin and onpressout do not appear in touchableopacity. Does it work correctly?

Comment: No it doesn't work. Using TouchableOpacity or TouchableWithoutFeedback makes no difference. They both work as buttons but when the style position is changed the hotspot remains in the same place.